# Python mu can not find one module that it could find previously. Idle can find the module

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to import the pyperclip module in Mu.  I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

I was able to import the module yesterday.  I can import other modules.  I can import and use the pyperclip module in IDLE.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the module using pip3.  It is in
/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: the answer is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684616/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyperclip

Comment: i posted a link to the answer. However, sometimes it helps to show what you have tried or where you have looked before.