# Trying to resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, pip

Trying to install third party modules on my mac using pip and I am getting this error (Using IDLE as the Python shell):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

(Have tried multiple modules and all return the same error)

I have installed the modules using:

```
pip3 install pyperclip
```

I can see that it has installed into the directory:

```
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Ive tried going through several of the posts posted on StackOverflow such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684616/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyperclip) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341614/modules-are-installed-using-pip-on-osx-but-not-found-when-importing) but after trying their steps I cant seem to resolve it.

which -a pip3 gives:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

which -a python3 gives:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

print(sys.version) gives:

```
3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec 7 2020, 12:44:01)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)]
```

pip --version gives:

```
pip 22.1.2 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Running `/usr/local/bin/python3 test1.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dxz/Downloads/test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you starting your python shell?

Comment: The outputs of your `which` commands are interesting, but you didn't show what `print(sys.version)` gives. Most likely you run Python 2 and installing for 3...

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for your reply, I am using IDLE Shell 3.9.1.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for your reply. `print(sys.version)` gives: `3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec 7 2020, 12:44:01)` `[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this command for seeing pip3 uses which python:

```
pip3 --version
```

But i guess you are not choosing right python to run your .py file

if you run your .py like this:

```
python3 main.py
```

You must be sure pip3 installing libraries to 'python3' linked python or you can run your main.py file with one of pip3 linked python

I mean if pip3 --version, it gives you which python linked with pip3

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

you can run your main.py with that python like this

```
/usr/bin/python3 main.py
```

but if you want to use best practice i recommend to use virtualenv

Comment: Thanks @mcagricaliskan. I updated the question with that command. Im still not sure what Im doing wrong though!

Comment: maybe you can use `python3 -m pip install pyperclip` it will use python3 linked python's pip and install it to python3 linked python

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Do you have any idea why what I was doing wasn't working?